# Python: while loop, how to keep counter?

Tags: python, class, graphics, while-loop

I am trying to create a game where there are 2 counters, a and b, and the game continues while a is not equal to 2 (initially 0) and b is not equal to 5 (initially 3), and b will increase everytime princess touches a certain point on the window. I am having trouble retaining the a and b values. I am building this game on the Zelle's Second Edition graphics framework built upon TKinter. My b never seems to rise above 4, and always resets back to 3 instead of ever reaching 5 to stop the while loop.

The relevant code is as follows (my image princess is a class with its own constructor and a method move), for the code dealing with b:

```
.... (irrelevant class informtion) ...

# I did not pass b into the __init__ 
# I only passed it into the move method, is that fine?

def move( self, mouse, b ):
    dX = 0
    if mouse.getY() > 300:
        dY = 2
    else:
        dY = -2

    self.img.move( dX, dY )

    if self.img.getAnchor().getY() == 350:
        newB = b + 1
        return newB
    else:
        return b
```

..... ( irrelevant code ) ...

```
while a != 2 or b!= 5:

    mouse = win.getMouse()
    b = 3

    princess.move( mouse, b )

    newB = princess.move( mouse, b )

    continue
```

Comment: b always resets back to 3 because you set it to 3 at the beginning of each iteration of the while loop and never change it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is just to do with scope, but on further digging it doesn't seem that's the case.

You have a while loop, which should end when `a==2 and b==5`, where they're both initially set to `0`, but in the loop, you're never changing `a`, so the first condition will always be `true`, and you'll get an infinite loop.

Your `b` is always reverting back to `3` because you have `b=3` in the loop, and you never set it to be anything else. I'm presuming that the `princess.move(...)` function returns the new position `b`.

Additionally, the `continue` at the end of the loop is completely superfluous.

Try this:

```
a,b = 0,0
while a != 2 or b!= 5:
    mouse = win.getMouse()
    b = princess.move(mouse, b)
```

As a side note, do you plan on doing something in there with `a` too? because currently it does not do anything, and so this should suffice:

```
b = 0
while b!= 5:
    mouse = win.getMouse()
    b = princess.move(mouse, b)
```

And then as a further note, called variables `a` and `b` is super unhelpful for anyone reading your code. Name them helpfully.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of b. Maybe you would like to say `b = princes.move(mouse,b)` in your while loop, so after that b may be incremented. In your code b stays with value 3 forever.